# Cant see assertions/ functional coverage in the environment

Tags: code-coverage, system-verilog, uvm

I used the covfile and select_functional command in the running options of the regression, and the coverage groups appear, but I can't see the assertions in IMC in order to map them. If I run a test and give the covfile command it works, but on regressions it doesn't.

Comment: Could not understand the question. You mean to say that with single run, you are getting all the data of functional coverage, but in regression, you are not getting it?

Comment: Yes. The functional coverage is not activated for regressions, although I use the same covfile as for the single run.

Comment: May be there can be some issue with your regression commands? It may not be passing the appropriate switched for functional coverage in the regression. Can you confirm, whether all the required switches have been passed or not?

Comment: All the switches were passed correctly. I manage to figure it out. The covfile command should be in the run_options of the regression, but also in the run_options of the compile script.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to setting up a compile/run and not code. It's the kind of question that belongs in the tool vendor's forums.

Comment: Which EDA tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The covfile command should be in the run_options of the regression, but also in the run_options of the compile script.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Cadence irun since you mentions IMC.  I also assume you are using vManager as your regression tool.  Why the coverage does not show up in regression ucd, I suspect you are not using the same snapshot in the regression as you are running the sim locally, which create snapshot with the covfile on the fly.  Double check your irun.log, see which snapshot it is using.  Then check the elaboration arguments of that snapshot (which you can find it under the .INCA_lib/ directory to see whether the snapshot has coverage turned on. (-coverage all)